# How to convert a PHP array into C#

Tags: php, arrays, c#-4.0

I have a php code

```
$r = array('key' => $key , 'command' => $command, 'hash' => $hash,'var1' => $var1);
```

its a associative array, I want to convert this code into c# but i think there is no associative arrays in c#

please help, thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` provides similar functionality to PHP's associative arrays.

```
IDictionary<String,Object> map = new Dictionary<String,Object>() {
    { "key", key },
    { "command", command },
    { "hash", hash },
    { "var1", var1 }
};
```

Note my use of C#'s object-initialization syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use anonymous types to achieve a simple NameValue anonymous object type. Although it's not exactly what you're asking for it's a common way to create arrays of anonymous objects with Linq:

```
var r = new [] {
          new {Name = "Key", Value = key},
          new {Name = "Command", Value = command},
          new {Name = "Hash", Value = hash},
          new {Name = "Var1", Value = var1}
        }
```